# Folder Access Error(folder doesn't exist)

Tags: c#, onedrive

I have created the application(C#) that displays the folder list and file list that get the information from OneDrive.

```
[Preparation]
0) I access the website(https://onedrive.live.com/?mkt=ja-jp) and run the following operation.
1) create the foloder under the root folder. 
2) put the document file in the folder that just created.
```

Error occurs when I try to access the folder that just created by using the application.

```
[Infomation]
Lang: C#
Use Class : WebRequest
AccessURL : https://apis.live.net/v5.0/${FOLDER_ID}/files?access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}
HTTP Method : GET
```

I describe the response result when an error occurs.

```
RESPONSE：(404) Not Found.
{
   "error": {
      "code": "resource_not_found",
      "message": "The resource '${FOLDER_ID}' doesn't exist."
   }
}
```

I was able to use up to Nov 21th 6:00(UTC).
I was no longer available from Nov 21th 8:00(UTC).

[Questions]
1) I do not know why this event has occurred. Do you know someone?
2) Is there a workaround?

Comment: Is your access token dependent on date (if getting verified against some database)?

Comment: check if `{FOLDER_ID}` is right

Comment: Hi, sdeep.I can get the files and folders under the root folder.So I think that it is not relevant for the access token. thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, Rohit. I check the ${FOLDER_ID}.it was correct.thank you for your help,

Comment: Can you tell me how you obtained `${FOLDER_ID}` and what its format is? The error you're seeing indicates that the folder ID you're using is not what the API expects.

Comment: Hi, daspek. ${FOLDER_ID} is "folder.3a4b4a2761cedcb2.3A4B4A2761CEDCB2!103".

Comment: Hi Dai, that ID is properly-formatted, but I think it's still invalid. Where did you obtain the ID? Anecdotally, '103' is a lower number than I would expect for a folder you created. Can you let me know where you got that ID?

Comment: Hi, daspek. Thank you your comment.I have confirmed that the different response in (a) and (b).(a): I have get the ${FOLDER_ID} that is used "me/skydrive".  (b):I have acquired the ${FOLDER_ID} of root folder from created folder under the root folder.

Comment: Hi Dai, I still don't understand where you're getting the ID's. Are you constructing them yourself based on data you see on onedrive.live.com? If so, that's not supported. The ID's on the website may not work in the API. If you're just using the API, you shouldn't see invalid ID's. I suspect that the !103 ID belongs to something that isn't accessible in the API, so I'm curious where you got that ID.